# Убрать последнюю запятую в масиве

Tags: php

```
$items = [];
foreach($product_filters as $product_filter) {
    $items[$product_filter["id"]][] = $product_filter;
}
foreach($items as $group) {
    echo "
    <tr><td class='description-left'>
        <span>{$group[0]["name"]}</span>
    </td>
    <td class='description-right'>";

    foreach($group as $filter) {
        echo "{$filter['group']}, ";
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Получается что ко всем элементам добавляется в конце запятая, нужно что бы к последнему элементу она не добавлялась

Результат кода

```
Заголовок 1     Текст 1, Текст 2,
Заголовок 2     Текст 3, Текст 4,
Заголовок 3     Текст 5,
```

А должно

```
Заголовок 1     Текст 1, Текст 2
Заголовок 2     Текст 3, Текст 4
Заголовок 3     Текст 5
```

Comment: используйте вместо цикла функцию [`join`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.join.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$numItems = count($group);
$i = 0;
foreach($group as $filter) {

   if(++$i === $numItems) echo "{$filter['group']} ";
   else echo "{$filter['group']}, ";

}
```

Comment: все оказалось очень просто, спасибо